# User login history in whole Domain

Tags: authentication, active-directory, event-log, event-viewer, domaincontroller

I'm actually looking for a way to get login history for a specific username.
I have tried these ways but didn't work:

**1. eventid 4624**

It only shows logins to the DC itself, Not in the entire domain. E.g. a user has logged in to the DC. So Eventviewer logs this as an event with eventid 4624. But if a user logs in to another server (not DC) , nothing will be logged in DC's Eventviewr.

**2. eventid 4769**

It's about tickets that DC creates and assigns. But is wasn't helpful.

So how can I get the login history of a user in entire domain?

Answer (score -1):

I reproduce your scenario and getting the expected result.

**Event ID 4624 - An account was successfully logged on.**

This event records every successful attempt to log on to the local computer. It includes critical information about the logon type (e.g. interactive, RemoteInteractive , batch, network, or service), SID, username, network information, and more. Monitoring this particular event is crucial as the information regarding logon type is not found in DCs.  you can get a user login history report without having to manually crawl through the event logs.

**Open the PowerShell ISE → Run the following script, adjusting the timeframe:**

```
# Find DC list from Active Directory
$DCs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter *
 
# Define time for report (default is 1 day)
$startDate = (get-date).AddDays(-1)
 
# Store successful logon events from security logs with the specified dates and workstation/IP in an array
foreach ($DC in $DCs){
$slogonevents = Get-Eventlog -LogName Security -ComputerName $DC.Hostname -after $startDate | where {$_.eventID -eq 4624 }}
 
# Crawl through events; print all logon history with type, date/time, status, account name, computer and IP address if user logged on remotely
 
 foreach ($e in $slogonevents){
 # Logon Successful Events
 # Local (Logon Type 2)
 if (($e.EventID -eq 4624 ) -and ($e.ReplacementStrings[8] -eq 2)){
 write-host "Type: Local Logon`tDate: "$e.TimeGenerated "`tStatus: Success`tUser: "$e.ReplacementStrings[5] "`tWorkstation: "$e.ReplacementStrings[11]
 }
 # Remote (Logon Type 10)
 if (($e.EventID -eq 4624 ) -and ($e.ReplacementStrings[8] -eq 10)){
 write-host "Type: Remote Logon`tDate: "$e.TimeGenerated "`tStatus: Success`tUser: "$e.ReplacementStrings[5] "`tWorkstation: "$e.ReplacementStrings[11] "`tIP Address: "$e.ReplacementStrings[18]
```

[image]

Reference : [Active Directory: How to Get User Login History using PowerShell - TechNet Articles - United States (English) - TechNet Wiki (microsoft.com)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51413.active-directory-how-to-get-user-login-history-using-powershell.aspx)

You can also try with one easiest alternative way using A tool like [ADAudit Plus](https://www.manageengine.com/products/active-directory-audit/download.html?source=loginhistory) that audits specific logon events as well as current and past logon activity to provide a list of all logon-related changes for particular user.

Step 1 : Download ADAdudit Plus in your VM and install it.

Step 2: Add your Server name ,Username and password.

Step 3 : Follow the below picture to get the logon details of **particular user.**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Reference : https://www.manageengine.com/products/active-directory-audit/kb/ad-user-login-history-report.html

Comment: I tried that again and I didn't get the result I wanted, Even after adding policies.... Did you do anything else that make it works?! ..... And I know about ADAudit Plus. But I can't use that because of some reasons. But I'm wondering how it works. Does it use 4624? or it has its collector on DCs? hope I can use its idea to get that result manually...

Comment: ManageEngine ADAudit Plus is a web based Active Directory change audit software. It provides
comprehensive reports on almost every change that occurs in your Windows Active Directory. Yes It use 4624 please to identify the successful logon please refer this document : https://www.manageengine.com/products/active-directory-audit/kb/windows-security-log-event-id-4624.html

Comment: Thanks. But it (4624 eventid) doesn't work for me :( and I don't know why.... I even tested it in different domains and situations but didn't work. Is anything especial needed to make it works??

Comment: Did you tried with same steps which I have provided for AD audit plus? Don't look for event id (4624) the website doesn't show in that way but you can get the login history of specified user from website itself as i did in above picture.

Comment: Please add your server in workgroup server and give credentials for the VM which you set.

Comment: verify the code before posting, please. As posted, it generates a syntax error (missing closing brackets) and generally, is not written well.